# Showing the number of y < x such that xRy is primitive recursive.

Tags: logic, recursion

> Suppose that $Rxy$ is a (primitive) recursive relation. Let the function $ \phi $ be defined as follows:
>
> $\phi(x)$ = the number of $y < x$ such that $Rxy$.
>
> Show that $ \phi $ is (primitive) recursive.

I'm not sure how I would begin to approach a construction for a recursive definition of this function. Would anyone have some ideas to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The representing function $F_R(x,y)$ is primitive recursive. Then we use $\sum_0^{x\dot{-}1}F_R(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Rxy$ is primitive recursive, there is a primitive recursive function $f \colon \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that

$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{, if } Rxy \\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $g \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be the primitive recursive function with constant value $0$. Also recall that $+ \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N, (x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is primitive recursive. [Please feel free to ask for further assistance, if you have trouble proving this fact.]

We now define a primitively recursive function $\phi \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ by letting $\phi(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $\phi(n+1) = +(\phi(n),f(n+1,n))$.

It's easy to verify (by induction on $x$) that $\phi(x) = \operatorname{card} (\{ y \mid y < x \wedge Rxy \})$.

Comment: Note that the same proof yields the following fact: If $f(x,y) = z$ is primitive recursive, then $g \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N, n \mapsto \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} f(n,i)$ is primitive recursive.